# How to copy/paste/consolidate values from multiple workbooks into MasterFile with multiple sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have three Workbooks which are my data sources "Data1, Data2 and Data3".

[image]

I want to put data from these three workbooks into a workbook named "MasterFile.xlsx" which has multiple sheets.

"Data1" will go into MasterFile Sheet1, "Data2" into MasterFile Sheet2 and "Data3" into MasterFile Sheet3. Every sheet of my MasterFile has a template for the data.

[image]

I can only consolidate data from one workbook into one sheet.

```
Public Sub Data()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim sht, msht As Worksheet
Dim lRowFile, lRowMaster As Long
Dim FirstDataSet As Integer

On Error Resume Next

Path = "C:\Users\source\"

Filename = "Data1.xlsx"

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)

Set sht = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(1)
Set msht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

lrF = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lRM = msht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
FirstDataSet = 2

For i = FirstDataSet To lrF
    lRM = msht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    msht.Range("B" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("A" & i).Value
    msht.Range("C" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("E" & i).Value
    msht.Range("E" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("B" & i).Value
    msht.Range("F" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("D" & i).Value
    msht.Range("I" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("F" & i).Value
    msht.Range("J" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("G" & i).Value
    msht.Range("K" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("H" & i).Value
    msht.Range("L" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("I" & i).Value
    msht.Range("M" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("J" & i).Value
    msht.Range("N" & lRM + 1).Value = sht.Range("K" & i).Value
Next
wbk.Close True

End Sub
```

Comment: May I know what steps you have done so far?

Comment: @Rommel Geluz...Thanks for your replied..I've already update my post..Please check it again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following might be helpful

```
Public Sub Data()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim sht, msht As Worksheet
    Dim shtLR, mshtLR As Long
    Dim FirstDataSet As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    Path = "C:\Users\source\"
    FirstDataSet = 2

    '------------------------------For Sheet1------------------------------
    Filename = "Data1.xlsx"
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    Set sht = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(1)

    Set msht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    shtLR = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    mshtLR = msht.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    msht.Range("B" & mshtLR + 1 & ":B" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("C" & FirstDataSet & ":C" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("C" & mshtLR + 1 & ":C" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("E" & FirstDataSet & ":E" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("E" & mshtLR + 1 & ":E" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("G" & FirstDataSet & ":G" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("F" & mshtLR + 1 & ":F" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("D" & FirstDataSet & ":D" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("I" & mshtLR + 1 & ":I" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("F" & FirstDataSet & ":F" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("J" & mshtLR + 1 & ":J" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("H" & FirstDataSet & ":H" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("K" & mshtLR + 1 & ":K" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("I" & FirstDataSet & ":I" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("L" & mshtLR + 1 & ":L" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("J" & FirstDataSet & ":J" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("M" & mshtLR + 1 & ":M" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("K" & FirstDataSet & ":K" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("N" & mshtLR + 1 & ":N" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("L" & FirstDataSet & ":L" & shtLR).Value

    wbk.Close True


    '------------------------------For Sheet2------------------------------
    Filename = "Data2.xlsx"
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    Set sht = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(1)

    Set msht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    shtLR = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    mshtLR = msht.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    msht.Range("B" & mshtLR + 1 & ":B" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("B" & FirstDataSet & ":B" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("C" & mshtLR + 1 & ":C" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("D" & FirstDataSet & ":D" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("D" & mshtLR + 1 & ":D" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("E" & FirstDataSet & ":E" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("F" & mshtLR + 1 & ":F" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("G" & FirstDataSet & ":G" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("G" & mshtLR + 1 & ":G" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("H" & FirstDataSet & ":H" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("J" & mshtLR + 1 & ":J" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("J" & FirstDataSet & ":J" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("K" & mshtLR + 1 & ":K" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("K" & FirstDataSet & ":K" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("L" & mshtLR + 1 & ":L" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("L" & FirstDataSet & ":L" & shtLR).Value

    wbk.Close True


    '------------------------------For Sheet3------------------------------
    Filename = "Data3.xlsx"
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    Set sht = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(1)

    Set msht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)

    shtLR = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    mshtLR = msht.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    msht.Range("B" & mshtLR + 1 & ":B" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("D" & FirstDataSet & ":D" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("C" & mshtLR + 1 & ":C" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("F" & FirstDataSet & ":F" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("E" & mshtLR + 1 & ":E" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("G" & FirstDataSet & ":G" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("F" & mshtLR + 1 & ":F" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("I" & FirstDataSet & ":I" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("I" & mshtLR + 1 & ":I" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("J" & FirstDataSet & ":J" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("J" & mshtLR + 1 & ":J" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("K" & FirstDataSet & ":K" & shtLR).Value
    msht.Range("K" & mshtLR + 1 & ":K" & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range("L" & FirstDataSet & ":L" & shtLR).Value

    wbk.Close True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT 1:________________________________________________________________________**

Following are the assumptions for smooth execution of the code:

**1.** All the data files are saved with names `Data1.xls`, `Data2.xls`, `Data3.xls`, `Data4.xls`, and so on.

**2.** `Column C` of data sheets have values. This is the column used to count the number of records in the sheet.

**3.** `Column B` of master file sheets is the column used to count the number of records in the sheet.

**4.** Count of sheets in `Master file` is same as number of data files. This will be determined using the length of `m1Array()`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Data()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim sht, msht As Worksheet
    Dim shtLR, mshtLR As Long
    Dim FirstDataSet, i, j As Integer
    Dim m1Array(), m2Array() As Variant

    On Error Resume Next

    'm1Array is the array where column names of the data files e.g. data1.xls, data2.xls, etc. are stored
    m1Array = Array(Array("B", "C", "E", "F", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N"), _
                    Array("B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "J", "K", "L"), _
                    Array("B", "C", "E", "F", "I", "J", "K"))

    'm2Array is the array where column names of the master file sheet are stored
    m2Array = Array(Array("C", "E", "G", "D", "F", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"), _
                    Array("B", "D", "E", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"), _
                    Array("D", "F", "G", "I", "J", "K", "L"))

    Path = "C:\Users\source\"
    FirstDataSet = 2

    'looping through all the data files
    For j = LBound(m1Array) To UBound(m1Array)
        Filename = "Data" & j + 1 & ".xlsx"
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
        Set sht = Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets(1)

        Set msht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(j + 1)

        shtLR = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        mshtLR = msht.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        'looping through each columns of the data sheet and corresponding master file sheet
        For i = LBound(m1Array(j)) To UBound(m1Array(j))
            msht.Range(m1Array(j)(i) & mshtLR + 1 & ":" & m1Array(j)(i) & mshtLR - 1 + shtLR).Value = sht.Range(m2Array(j)(i) & FirstDataSet & ":" & m2Array(j)(i) & shtLR).Value
        Next i

        wbk.Close True
    Next j
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT 2:________________________________________________________________________**

You can make another array for file names as follows:

```
Dim fileArray() As Variant
fileArray = Array("Schools.xlsx", "Students.xlsx", "Managers.xlsx")
```

Then replace below line

```
Filename = "Data" & j + 1 & ".xlsx"
```

to

```
Filename = fileArray(j)
```

Comment: @Mrig..Thank you for your great time Sir! What if I had 20 workbooks or more, do I need to do this?

Comment: @jhovyn - If you have uniform data or a fixed pattern (which is not there in first three sheets) then few lines of code can be re-used or else I'm afraid to say you have to take a long and ugly option.

Comment: @Mrig..Thank you Sir for your advice and help!

Comment: @jhovyn - Give me some more time I could be able to provide you a better solution.

Comment: @Mrig..Thank you Sir! I really appreciate your help! I'm willing to wait since I'm just still learning... Thank you again and have a Blessed Day!

Comment: @Mrig...Sir I have a question, what if my source file name are not Data1,Data2,Data3? Let say the filename of my source file are Schools.xlsx,Students.xlsx and Managers.xlsx. How will I adjust? Thank you again sir

Comment: @jhovyn - See EDIT2.

Comment: @Mrig..Thank you! Sir last question, what if I have let say monthly sales on my data source on column M:AT? how to copy that range?

Comment: @jhovyn - Use `msht.Range("M1:AT5").Value = sht.Range("M1:AT5").Value`. Change range as needed.

Comment: @Mrig..Thank you Sir! I know this is too much but can you please show me sir? I dont know where and how will I put this code `msht.Range("M1:AT5").Value = sht.Range("M1:AT5").Value`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145520/discussion-between-mrig-and-jhovyn).